# How to render html code with asp.net class

Tags: asp.net, html-rendering, dynamic-html

I need to be able to add a dynamic html code to a random cshtml page using my class:

```
public class HTMLRenderClass
{
    //--here I generate html code
    public void RenderControll()
    {
        LiteralControl ControlGroup = new LiteralControl();
        ControlGroup.Text = "<h1>Here will be html code generated above</h1>";
        Page p = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
        if (p != null) p.Controls.Add(ControlGroup);
        else { throw new UserFriendlyException("Page still null"); }
    }
}
```

so that inside cshtml I could call it like

```
@{
HTMLRenderClass c = new HTMLRenderClass();
c.RenderControll();
}
```

But the problem  is that I don't know how to add my html to the page I need, because "HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page" is always null. Are there any solutions of that situation in which I still could use c.RenderControll() method without passing any "Page object" parameters?
If not, then what exactly should I pass to my class to place my dynamic html block inside static one?

Comment: You are using Asp.Net MVC right? its not in the tag.

Comment: Is your HTMLRenderClass inside MVC applicaiton?

Comment: In MVC the handler will usually be a 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler', not a 'Page', so this line:

    'Page p = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;'

will always return null.

Comment: Oh, I went completely wrong way. The simple solution is: public string RenderControll()
        {
            //generate html code
            return htmlcode;
        }
and on page:
    @Html.Raw(c.RenderControll());